# Updating a column value from the value of the other table SQL

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have a table `chatmessages` that has a chatId, incomingId, outgoingId column, and I have another table `chatmembers` which has a chatId, usersId column. Also another table `chat` that contains only the chatId, and the usersId initializer of the chat which is user1

[image]

[image]

Now, I want to copy the chatId from `chatmembers` to `chatmessages` where there are the same users inside it, example, the incomingId 83 and outgoingId 81 has the same chatId in `chatmembers`

[image]

I have this query but it doesnt work

```
UPDATE chatmessages SET chatId = 
(SELECT c.chatId FROM chat AS c INNER JOIN (SELECT chatId FROM chatmembers WHERE usersId = incomingId) AS uc ON c.chatId = uc.chatId 
INNER JOIN (SELECT chatId FROM chatmembers WHERE companyId = outgoingId) AS cc ON uc.chatId = cc.chatId)
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you could use `join`s.  The following uses MySQL syntax:

```
update chatmessages cm join
       chatusers cuo
       on cuo.userid = cm.outgoingid join
       chatusers cui
       on cui.userid = cm.incomingid and
          cui.chatid = cuo.chatid
   set cm.chatid = cuo.chatid;
```

Comment: Thank you, uhm may I know whats wrong with the code I did before? should it work too or should I need to use JOIN when it comes to UPDATE?

Comment: @DanncarloReformado . . . I do not know what is the problem with your code.  I find it very hard to read.

Comment: Your answer worked, I just want to know if whats wrong with my previous UPDATE query sir thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you must write this query in array and next make execute,
also use double quotes in

```
(SELECT c.chatId FROM chat AS c 
INNER JOIN (SELECT chatId FROM chatmembers WHERE usersId = incomingId) AS uc ON c.chatId = uc.chatId 
INNER JOIN (SELECT chatId FROM chatmembers WHERE companyId = outgoingId)
```

like this

```
("SELECT c.chatId FROM chat AS c 
INNER JOIN (SELECT chatId FROM chatmembers WHERE usersId = incomingId) AS uc ON c.chatId = uc.chatId 
INNER JOIN (SELECT chatId FROM chatmembers WHERE companyId = outgoingId")
```

Comment: Sorry but this isnt my question. Thanks